# How to retrieve the full ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 14.04, unity

My ubuntu 14.04 edition desktop has suddenly changed to the lightweight desktop . Here are some pics of this desktop it changed to:

[image: No sidebar shown and apps appear upon clicking the activities tab]

[image: Footprint logo]

So how can I return the original Ubuntu desktop look , this look is very annoying. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the "lightweight" environment. It appears you have installed the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package. You need to install `ubuntu-desktop` and make sure you choose *Unity* at the log-in screen instead of *GNOME*.

You can also just run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to do a more complete swap.

Comment: It tells me E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-gnome
and trying to install ubuntu gives : ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.

Comment: Sorry. Updated answer. Package is actually ubuntu-gnome-desktop.

Comment: Before I can see your update I tried autoremove gnome-shell and it worked except that i got a loop at login screen which I have also fixed.
Anyway it works now thanks for your help

Comment: There you go ;)